# PowerShell Poker Hand - Issue with building an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm working on a side project (not for class) and am trying to better myself with PowerShell. Im working through a problem where I am building a Poker Hand with the Rank and Suit of the card.

This first example works just fine

```
$a='A'
$num=2..9
$jkq='J','K','Q'
```

This example does not work

```
$rank = 'A'+2..9+'J','K','Q'
```

I know I have ran into this issue before but can't remember what the term is for what I am doing wrong. I've tried a few methods of isolating the variables inside of the array build, but none of them seemed to work.

For clarification, the first code example builds an array with 12 elements. The second example builds an array with 1 element that is `"A2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9J K Q"`
Obviously, this looks like a type error between building a string and an array. however, even with specifying `[array]$rank` I do not get a successfully built array.

This also does not work

```
[array]$rank = @('A'+(2..9)+'J','K','Q')
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$rank = 2..10 +'J','Q','K','A'` ? And as it begins with an array ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since **you're attempting *array concatenation***, you must **make sure that your *first* operand is an *array*** (too):

```
@('A') + 2..9 + 'J','K','Q'
```

`@('A')` ensures that `'A'` is an array, using PowerShell's [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--).
**Important**: `@(...)` *ensures* that `...` is an array, but it doesn't necessarily *construct* one - if what `...` evaluates to already *is* an array, it is *left alone*, loosely speaking.

**Alternatively**, you can use the **unary form of `,`** - PowerShell's [array-*construction* operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#comma-operator-) (the "comma operator") - to construct `'A'` as a single-element array:

```
, 'A' + 2..9 + 'J','K','Q'
```

Both solutions result in an array that is the equivalent of (expressed as source code):

```
'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'J', 'K', 'Q'
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

**With operators such as `+` that have *type-specific overloads*, it is generally 
the *LHS*'s type that determines the behavior**.

In your case, the (first) LHS is a (single) *string*, `'A'`, therefore `+` performs *string* concatenation.

That is, the remaining operands were appended to string `'A'` in their *stringified form*, which in the case of arrays means a space-separated list of the array's elements.

A simplified example:

```
PS> 'A' + ('B', 'C')
AB C
```

That is, the stringification of array `'B', 'C'` - which is the equivalent of `'B C'` - was appended to string `'A'`.